# Mechanical Drawing Ventilation Abbreviations - Canada

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing, drawings

I'm trying to figure out what the abbreviations are for exhaust fans in mechanical drawings. I've posted an example below, which is shown in the legend as Supply Air (SA), along with its size and distribution in L/s. I have a few others such as EA, RC, and SB but am unable to figure out what those stand for. Thanks!

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Which company produced these? Did you check the rest of their documentation? They will usually supply a legend - you have cropped so much that it may be there.